# Chose logic based on request body in NestJS

Tags: typescript, express, controller, nestjs

I have a controller like this:

```
@Controller("workflow")
export class TaskWorkflowController {
  public constructor(
    private readonly jobApplicationActivityWorkflow: JobApplicationActivityService
  ) {}

  @Post("/:job-application-activity")
  public startWorkflow(
    @Body() body: StartJobApplication | StartJobActivity,
    @Param("job-application-activity") jobApplicationActivity: string
  ): void {
    switch (jobApplicationActivity) {
      case "job-application":
        return this.jobApplication.execute(body);
      case "job-activity":
        return this.jobActivity.execute(body);
      default:
        throw new Error("Invalid workflow");
    }
  }
```

I want to trigger different logic based on `job-application-activity` param.
The problem is that the body is the type `StartJobApplication | StartJobActivity` and my services are the type `StartJobApplication` and `StartJobActivity`.

How I should handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first hurdle you'll find with this is that you can't perform validation due to Typescript not reflecting the union type. If that's not a deal breaker for you, then you could make a type guard instead of a switch statement and do something along the lines of

```js
@Controller("workflow")
export class TaskWorkflowController {
  public constructor(
    private readonly jobApplicationActivityWorkflow: JobApplicationActivityService
  ) {}

  @Post("/:job-application-activity")
  public startWorkflow(
    @Body() body: StartJobApplication | StartJobActivity,
    @Param("job-application-activity") jobApplicationActivity: string
  ): void {
    if (jobApplicationActivity.propertyOnlyOnStartJobApplication) {
        return this.jobApplication.execute(body);
    } else if(jobApplicationActivity.propertyOnlyOnStartJobActivity)
        return this.jobActivity.execute(body);
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid workflow");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's there a way to do this check with pipes?

Comment: You could write your own pipe for it and return the proper type yourself, and then do a `switch` with an `instanceof` but don't count on anything pre-built